# Find SQL Server database file settings for clustered environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, configuration, cluster-computing

How can you find file settings (initial size, autogrowth) for a clustered SQL Server database?  In a non-clustered database you are able to read the settings from database properties, tab Files, or with a SQL script against system views (sys.database_files and sys.master_files). I'm not able to use these methods when trying to read file settings for a clustered SQL Server instance database. They show nothing. The database is in production and I have limited access to the database, is that the reason why I can't get any values for file settings? I work as CM for the system (new at the position) and want to go through all points that can cause performance bottlenecks. In the test environments the file growth were set to the default value for autogrowth 1 MB which I think is to low for a database with the size of 50 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be anything to do with the clustering, it will be that the DBA has limited your permissions to the database so that you can't access any of the information.

The good thing is that if they have limited your access to the system and they are controlling it, then it's up to them to change the settings to a more appropriate value :)